# Extension of REST in IBM WCS

Tags: rest, websphere-commerce, wcs

I have been trying to write a customized REST and extend the defualt IBM REST framework, and I have been succeeded in it but the issue I have been facing is the processing time of data-import Query( written in wc-dataimport-preprocess-XXXXX.xml).

It is taking too long to get data in preprocessing, because the query includes B/CLOB columns.

Is there any way to optimize the process and reduce the processign time of query in pre processing?

**NOTE:** Without LOB columns, data-import is working fine.